# Accessing Db in RequestFilter

Tags: servicestack, requestfiltering

I'm using ServiceStack 4 and currently access the database (`Db`) in a service without any issue. However, in a `RequestFilter` or a `ResponseFilter`, I do not have access to the `Db` property.

Is there any other way to access the database than resolving an `<IDbConnection>` instance in the `Execute` method of the filter? I tried resolving from a registered `IDbConnection`, but it is not as seemless as in a `Service` and the connection is closed.

I'm trying to keep it DRY and avoid breaking the Request chain.

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve a `IDbConnection` from the `IDbConnectionFactory` that's registered in your AppHost IOC (i.e. you can only resolve registered dependencies), e.g:

```
using (var db = HostContext.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().Open()) 
{
    //...
}
```

This is also how the base `Service` class [resolves its IDbConnection](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Service.cs#L82).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer @mythz! However, I was trying to avoir surrounding each `Db` call with a `using` directive. Ended up checking your implementation of `Service` and copied the getter, and the `Dispose`. But thanks for the answer! :)